# Word displays a line separator between pages instead of page breaks

Tags: microsoft-word

I want Microsoft Word to display page breaks between pages, instead of this line separator between my pages as in the following picture:
[image]

How can I change this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Place your mouse pointer exactly on the separator line and double click. This toggles the display of white space between pages.

Answer (score 2):

You can go to **Word Options** choose **Display** and under **Page Display Options**  click in the square near **Show White Space Between Pages in Print Layout View**
Or like Atzmon's advice for quicker way just point on the **top or bottom edge** of a page and **double-click**.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

- Click the Microsoft Office Button, and then click Word Options.
- In the left pane, click Customize.
- In the Choose commands from list, click All Commands.
- Click White Space Between Pages, click Add, and then click OK.

The White Space Between Pages option will appear on the Quick Access Toolbar.